# Why nasm says I have error in the assembly g++ created?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, nasm

I have this c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

  char chr[] = "111111111111";
  int pop = 9999;
  cout << chr << (pop+1) << endl;

}
```

when I do in the shell (64 bit linux) `g++ -S hello.cpp` I get assembly code :

when I use on it `nasm hello.s` it says it contains a lot of errors such as:

```
instruction needed
expression syntax error
symbol `popq' redefined
```

maybe it is because it is 64bit? how can I compile the .s I created with the g++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assembler generated by GCC is using what is known as AT&T syntax, which differs from the Intel-syntax used by nasm. You have to use the GCC assembler (`as`)  to compile GCC generated assembler files.

See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler#Criticism.

For more information about the GNU assembler syntax, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax.

Answer (score 3):

There are several assembler syntaxes for x86. In particular, `nasm` and `gas` (the assembler inside [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)) have different syntaxes.

Very often, GCC is configured to emit assembly code using `gas` syntax. You could find out what GCC is doing with eg `g++ -O -v -c yourcode.cc` and you can learn how GCC was configured with `gcc -v` or `g++ -v` alone.

And you might invoke GCC as `g++ -S -fverbose-asm yourcode.cc`  to get a more readable `yourcode.s`